# Https causes too many redirects on Safari

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, safari

I recently started redirecting my domain to `https` and I am getting a "too many redirects" error on Safari, especially on mobile. Everything works fine on any computers and in any other browsers.

Here's how I've done my redirects.

## for main domain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I also disabled Cloudflare because it was causing issues with my SSL and I fixed some issues with DNS propagation.

**EDIT:**

It affects all safari browsers except for computers and deleting the cache doesn't solve the issue. I only have one domain, but a few subdomains.

I do have other directives in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^folder\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/all\-categories\/folder\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Changing host solved this problem for me.

Comment: If this problem is only affecting one browser, on one machine(?) then it strongly suggests a client-side caching issue. If there was something wrong with the directives in .htaccess then it would affect _all_ browsers on _all_ machines. Do you have multiple domains? Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^folder\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/all\-categories\/folder\/$1" [R=301,L]
> ```

Since you are redirecting *everything* to `https`, you should also be doing this in the above redirect. Otherwise you are going to end up with additional (unnecessary) redirects. So this should be rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/?(.*) https://example.com/all-categories/folder/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have also tidied up the regex and *substitution* (this looks like something cPanel would generate?). There is no need for all the backslash escapes (and double quotes) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. And the backslash escape in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is also superfluous.

However, I doubt whether this alone is enough to satisfy Safari (mobile). (?)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I decided to change web host because my website was down too often lately so I will try this solution shortly.

Comment: Any luck at the new host?

Comment: Everything works well with the new host, but I still rewrote my redirects just to have a cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using CloudFlare's Flexible SSL; the web server might not be able to correctly identify when the connection should be over SSL and when it shouldn't.

As such you should attempt to [install Mod_CloudFlare on your webserver](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare) to resolve this, if you can't do this, you can instead set your SSL environment variable from the X-Forwarded-Proto header in your Apache .htaccess:

> SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

Comment: I disabled CloudFlare.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using following method

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

is causing the error. use

> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$

to fix it.