# .htaccess too many redirections in Safari

Tags: .htaccess, safari

I have htaccess file consisting of

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL on for 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/m/log
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/log
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/stil 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/slike 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/slikce 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It runs fine on basically any other device except iPhone. How to fix it?

It happens only on `/m/log` while using iPhone6, it's fine on iPhone 4. It happens regardless of whether the site is accessed via `HTTP` or `HTTPS`, or via `www` or the bare domain.

Comment: What URLs are you requesting that results in "too many redirections"? And what redirections do you see in the network traffic? Presumably you have cleared the browser cache? Curious, another recent question regarding too many redirects in Safari mobile only... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935962/https-causes-too-many-redirects-on-safari

Comment: It happens only on /m/log while using iphone6 its fine on iphone 4

Comment: Does it make a difference if you request `http`/`https` and/or `www` or bare domain? For instance, if you requested `https://example.com/m/log` (ie. `https` and no `www`) then your .htaccess file shouldn't be issuing any redirect at all. However, if you requested `http://www.example.com/m/log` (ie. `http` and `www` subdomain) then 2 external redirects will be issued.

Comment: Same thing in all cases. www/non www and https/http

Comment: If you look at the network traffic (on any device/browser, eg. Chrome/Desktop), do you see any _redirects_ when accessing `https://example.com/m/log`? (I'm not sure how you would test Safari/iPhone - but the network traffic _should be_ the same.)

Comment: I dont think so. Im not 100% sure i understand what you mean thou. You can try https://vetercek.com/m/log/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had a quick look at the network traffic on the site itself, it would seem that when serving `https://example.com‌/m/log` (ie. the "secure" page), you have a few images (including the `favicon.ico`) that are being redirected back to `http`. This results in "mixed content" and an insecure connection. Some browsers might throw up a warning or simply not display the usual "padlock". (Google Chrome omits the green padlock but only highlights the "mixed content" issue when examining​ the security information.) This needs to be corrected.

If the user-agent (ie. Safari on iPhone 6) attempts to "correct this" (to make it secure) by re-requesting the secure resource then you could well end up with "too many redirects" (a redirect loop).

The images (URLs) in question.

- `/slikce/smile.png` (Curiously, this also returns an `X-Pad: avoid browser bug` response header?)
- `/log/slike/1471075891/tm_13950809_10209500982108999_1789026171_o.jpg`
- `/favicon.ico`

All the above URLs appear on the "secure" HTML page, however, they get 301 redirected back to `HTTP` following the rules in your .htaccess file.

(It also appears that the HTTPS requests are handled by Apache, but the `HTTP` requests are handled by Nginx?)

Incidentally, I'm also seeing this error while testing your site in Safari on iOS 9 (iPad)...

> Safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occurred.

Comment: Thank you that was realy helpfull. Unfortunately i canot put ssl all over the page but i think i manage to solve it for now. Will try tomorrow on Ipad

Comment: Ok. I fixed .htacess so i get all https however it still dont work on ipad. Same error

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by using following method used in redirection

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}  !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

is causing the error. use

> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$

to fix it.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me - I examined (on Chrome) the Network for the page that was having redirect issue (on Safari). On Chrome, none of the requested resources were http, so the first solution above did not work for me.