# Error 500 Too Many Redirects on Apache Specific to iOS Devices

Tags: php, ios, apache, .htaccess

So this is a weird one.  I have a system that functions in 2 parts:

1. Fill out form.  Submit sends an email to the email entered in the form with a link that has a unique string as a _GET parameter
2. Click link in the email, goes to a page that validates based on the string

When I click on this link from Windows or Android, everything is perfectly fine.  If I click it on an iOS device, I get "Error, too many redirects" in both Safari and Chrome.  I've cleared cache, rebooted iOS devices (iPad Air 2, iPad Mini, iPhone 6S, iPod Touch), tried hostname and IP access, tried moving directories around, I've stripped literally everything out of the page in question except for the HTML tag, BODY tag, and a simple "Oh, hai" and get the same result.  The validation page is in the same folder as the form page.  The validation code works on another web server on the same machine (LigHTTPd).  All of this tells me that the code is fine.

I spent a good chunk of the day trying to figure this out and everything I've found thus far suggests that it's related to .htaccess.  Perfectly understandable.  **There is no .htaccess file in this directory.  There are no rules in the general Apache conf file that pertain specifically to this subdirectory.**  Another weird thing is that this code was 80% copied from another directory with that site still functioning as expected (i.e. validation link click works fine).

The logs don't indicate anything besides a 500 error.

So to summarize:

1. Windows: Good
2. Android: Good
3. iOS: Fails with error 500, too many redirects on both Chrome and Safari
4. Affects all iOS devices
5. Not .htaccess related (Near as I can tell)
6. Only affects this particular site
7. Not cache related
8. Not hostname/IP related
9. Works fine in another web server

I would love to post the URL but this is for a paying client.

So I'm asking if anyone knows a way I can troubleshoot this.
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Too many redirects is generally an issue with `header()` make sure you `die()` after redirect.

Comment: Curious, I've encountered a few questions lately that appear to have similar problems with iOS/Safari. For example: [.htaccess too many redirections in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941981/htaccess-too-many-redirections-in-safari) and [Https causes too many redirects on Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935962/https-causes-too-many-redirects-on-safari)

Comment: "There is no .htaccess file in this directory." - Do you have _any_ .htaccess file along the filesystem path? So, what redirects do you see in the network traffic (or access logs) for this request?

Comment: in your apache config files (vhost if you have them), include a line like this `LogLevel trace6 rewrite:trace6` , and observe the error.log as events unfold. You may get a hint as to what differentiates the way the iOS request is being served. I also log rewrite rules because i use them (but not in .htaccess files).   You can target each module of apache with its own log level (from notice to trace8), and the general log itself.

Comment: Xorifelse that's the thing, there's no redirect there.  There should be, but for troubleshooting I stripped out everything so the page just output "Oh hai!", no CSS, no JS, no PHP, no meta redirect, nothing.

@w3dk I'll check those links, thank you.  Unfortunately, when you google this 95% of it is related to Wordpress which doesn't apply to me.  I checked some of the .htaccess links and didn't have any luck.  Yes, there are a few other .htaccess files in folders at the same hierarchical level, but nothing above its hierarchical level.

Comment: "I stripped out everything" - if you've removed _all_ the redirects, it's still possible you are seeing a cached redirect if these were previously 301s (301 redirects will be cached by the browser). (Although the type of redirect you mention in the question should perhaps be a 302, or some other non-permanent redirect?)

Comment: Ok, so this is infuriating.  I added @YvesLeBorg's LogLevel change.  The service was VERY slow to restart and was responding to requests very slowly.  In fact, it tripped my NMS.  Regardless, when I tapped the link with the LogLevel in the conf file, it worked!  I commented out the LogLevel line, restarted Apache and tested again, it worked!  I'm at a loss.  This was misbehaving over multiple days with me clearing Safari cache numerous times.  Tested on multiple devices, all appear to be working.  I am using CloudFlare, but cleared its cache and had it in development mode.  I hope it stays up

Comment: @w3dk I cleared cache everywhere I could find it; device, CloudFlare, even tested 16+ hours after the last test.  Also, I fired up an iOS device that had never attempted to connect to this site at all in any way, shape, or form.  They were META HTTP redirects due to some strange issues I was having with PHP header redirects and delaying the actual redirect a bit.  Not ideal, but works on another, almost identical site, on the same server.